# CUDA opencv building fails - missing file that is actually there

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to do the following: getting to work

- CUDA 9.1 with
- openCV 3.4.2 and
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (v 14.0 Update 3) on
- Windows 7 Enterprise x64 SP 1 using
- CMake 3.12.0

and also searching for others with the same problem - no success there.

I have worked through [this tutorial](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/build-compile-opencv-3-4-in-windows-with-cuda-9-0-and-intel-mkl-tbb/) on getting the software to work together. I do not intend to use Intel MKL and TBB.

I have succeeded in

- installing CUDA
- generating the Makefiles for openCV with CMake, and having the CUDA libraries included without any mistakes (barring the download of optional stuff, as the PC I am working on is to stay off the internet)
- generating the .sln solution file for building openCV in Visual Studio

The **problem** is in the next step - building openCV. **The compiler claims that "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp" cannot be opened by gpu_mat_cu** when it tries to build opencv_world. The thing is that the include path works according to Visual Studio - it detects the right file in the gpu_mat.cu. The project (opencv_world) has the right directory in its include paths as static path.

I am new to Visual Studio (I worked in Linux with QT, CUDA and openCV before), so I am not too sure I am not missing some kind of settings I should change.
The opencv_world.hpp only consists of #define instructions. I have tried deleting the include of opencv_world.hpp and instead just defining the parameter in gpu_mat.cu itself, but if I do, the next include (that, again, VS finds the path to without problems) is not resolved.
I guess there is something obvious I am missing, but I don't seem to be able to resolve this issue, so thanks in advance for your help.

Cr4sh

P.S.: The files CMake wanted to download for openCV and failed at (obviously; no internet connection) are: opencv_ffmpeg.dll, opencv_ffmped64.dll, ffmpeg_version.cmake, ippicv_2017u3_win_intel64_general_20180518.zip, res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel and opencv_face_detector_uint8.pb

I'd add the CMakeCache.txt file in a spoiler tag, but it has too many characters. If you think it would help, let me know and I'll upload it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got **the solution**, just in case someone stumbles over the same problem: it's the most simple thing that everybody knows until they don't - **my include path contained a white space** that apparently somewhere was treated as a String divider for whatever interprets that path.